# How can i deploy compilled contract with node/web3 and metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask, nodejs

Does anybody knows how to deploy smart contract with node/web3 and using unlocked metamask account. I mean over internet it is advised to use `HDWalletProvider` with mnemonic but I want that user that is on my website could deploy contract from personal metamask account (like this REMIX do at the moment: when push "deploy" contract then metamask pops up with my personal account)! I want same thing but from my webpage where users can deploy contracts from their personal account! Thank you

How to change provider to user users personal metamask account ?

```js
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const compiledContract = require('../build/deal.json');

// TODO >>> HOW TO CHANGE THIS PROVIDER TO GET ACCOUNT FROM UNLOCKED METAMASK (WHITCH IS USERS PERSONAL ACCOUNT)
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  'twelve words mnemonic twelve words mnemonic twelve words mnemonic twelve words mnemonic',
  'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<key>'
);

let web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new 
web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<key>')); // http://localhost:8545

(async () => { const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  console.log(`Attempting to deploy from account: ${accounts[0]}`);
  const deployedContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(compiledContract.abi)
    .deploy({
      data: '0x' + compiledContract.evm.bytecode.object,
      arguments: [3, 5]
    })
    .send({
      from: accounts[0],
      gas: '2000000'
    });

  console.log(
    `Contract deployed at address: ${deployedContract.options.address}`
  );

  provider.engine.stop();
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

From [Metamask FAQ](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check):

```js
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
  web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
  // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
  web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}
```

or, adapted to your code, should look like this:

```js
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // fallback - use Infura
  let web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
      "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<key>"));
}
```